# Configparser Integers

Tags: python, parsing, config, configparser

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Previously, the code was this:

```
volume = min(60, max(30, volume))
```

However, after trying with configparser, I keep getting a 500 error on my Twilio Server.

```
volume_min = configParser.get('config_searchandplay', 'volume_min')
volume_max = configParser.get('config_searchandplay', 'volume_max')
volume = min(volume_max, max(volume_min, volume)) # Max Volume Spam Protection
```

`CONFIG.ini`:

```
[config_searchandplay]
#Volume Protection
volume_max = 90
volume_min = 10
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem of your method is that [`ConfigParser.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) gives you a (unicode) string. So you should convert the values first to number (using `int()` or `float()`):

```
vol_max = int(configParser.get('config_searchandplay', 'volume_max'))
vol_min = int(configParser.get('config_searchandplay', 'volume_min'))
volume = min(vol_max, max(vol_min, volume))
```

Or use the respective convenience methods: [`ConfigParser.getint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.getint) or  [`ConfigParser.getfloat`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.getfloat):

```
vol_max = configParser.getint('config_searchandplay', 'volume_max')
vol_min = configParser.getint('config_searchandplay', 'volume_min')
```

---

Although `min` works on strings:

```
>>> min(u'90',u'10')
u'10'
```

It will not always give the answer you are looking for since it does a string comparison. The following is what you want to avoid:

```
>>> min(u'9',u'10')
u'10'
```

Therefore you need to convert the string to a number:

```
>>> min(int(u'9'),(u'90'))
9
```

Comment: Thank you very much agold, will be testing out soon!

Answer (score 20):

You should use

```
ConfigParser.getint(section, option)
```

rather than casting.

```
volume_max = configParser.getint('config_searchandplay', 'volume_max')
volume_min = configParser.getint('config_searchandplay', 'volume_min')
volume = min(volume_max, max(volume_min, volume)) # Max Volume Spam Protection
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to convert any string to a number if it is possible (Note, you need very rear a string represented number). Here is my helper function from [here](https://gist.github.com/raczben/76cd1229504d82115e6427e00cf4742c).

```
def number(a, just_try=False):
    try:
        # First, we try to convert to integer.
        # (Note, that all integer can be interpreted as float and hex number.)
        return int(a)
    except Exception:
        # The integer convertion has failed because `a` contains others than digits [0-9].
        # Next try float, because the normal form (eg: 1E3 = 1000) can be converted to hex also.
        # But if we need hex we will write 0x1E3 (= 483) starting with 0x
        try:
            return float(a)
        except Exception:
            try:
                return int(a, 16)
            except Exception:
                if just_try:
                    return a
                else:
                    raise

def number_config(config):
    ret_cfg = {}
    for sk, sv in config._sections.items():
        ret_cfg[sk] = {k:number(v, True) for k,v in sv.items()}
    return ret_cfg
```